# Collectively evaluate a number of normal distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, prediction, model, validation

I build a few models, each model will produce a normal distribution for the value of a future event. For example, model M1 will produce a normal distribution $n(30, 5^2)$, and the value of the future event observed is 24. Likewise,

M2-> $n(40, 10^2)$, observation: 35

M3-> $n(10, 2^2)$, observation: 20

How do I evaluate the underlying theory used to build M1, M2, M3?

Comment: Are all the observations statistically independent? If so, your theory provides a way to collect a set of independent *standardized* observations by dividing the difference between each observation and its predicted value by the standard deviation. That reduces your question to "how can I compare a set of observations to a standard normal distribution," one that is answered in [many threads here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=fit+normal+distribution+test+goodness).

Comment: Thanks to @whuber. All observations are independent. I can transform all to standard normal distribution and test the goodness of fit for the observations.

Comment: The answer by Henry in the duplicate thread lists some of your best options.